# Export/import firestore project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have firestore project. However I want to clone it (export/import) to a new project so I can provide access to that to developer to play with (I don't him to mess with the original one)

Is this possible and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in data export or import in Cloud Firestore yet.

However Cloud Firestore has an API, with which you can build your own import and export tools.

From the comments: As of August 2018 one can use the new export/import feature in firestore:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

Comment: Thanks Frank. Hopefully you guys add this feature soon

Comment: As of August 2018 one can use the new export/import feature in firestore:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

Comment: Thanks for flagging @DanielDimitrov.  I added that info to my answer.